# How to calculate the similarity percentage of two Images , Same as like below Image I want to implement it in my Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

[image]

If anybody know how to implement this, give me suggestion or implementation of code. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: compare two images and get a % difference value
[this link will help to and give some idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742958/how-to-compare-images-using-opencv-in-ios-iphone/15743078)

Answer (score 0):

I think for compare two images, you need to fetch each pixel's color and compare them.

You can use http://openframeworks.cc link.
This provide feature to read each pixel's color.

Comment: How to use this one

Comment: Please review this link. http://openframeworks.cc/learning/  You need to look into it.

Comment: @Bitto : This link describe general information for all platform. I had made one image processing app using this framework. So, I suggest this.