# Comparing images by percentage in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, image, image-processing

I'm trying to find a way to compare images. My point is not to check if images are the same(equal) but if they are similar by some percentage let's say `80,90%`. For now, all I need is a way to compare two images and later on ill try to implement that and compare the image with a bunch of images from my database. I know about `Core ML framework` but right now I need a specific function to do the work! I know that this is not simple but I also know that there are a lot of ninjas among the members!

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by "similar"? is image rotated by x deg similar? is inverted colors image similar? is image moved down 5 px similar? your question is too general to give a proper answer.

Comment: The point is let's say we have two images one of it has a blue car on it and other also some car... The main purpose will be if I lost my dog will I be able to find it based on someone's post with a picture of my dog!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well comparing images by percentage will include its pixel by pixel reading, Grey scale, RGB and Alpha factors etc. You need to explore few third party SDK's and libraries to achieve required functionality. One choice could be OpenCV. Also [AIImageCompare](https://github.com/aleph7/AIImageCompare) library also might be of your interest.

I don’t think there is any single SDK or dev tool that’s really going to be the backbone of a project like this, but there are a couple you could have a look at that may be of use:

LTU Technologies - offers a variety of features like color searching, image matching, image similarity, sine comparison, content tracking, and more. Probably one of if not the top image recognition company out there.

CloudSight - is a simple REST API for understanding your images. You send them an image and they send back a description of its contents.

Cloud Vision - allows developers to easily integrate vision detection features within applications, including image labeling, face and landmark detection, optical character recognition (OCR), and tagging of explicit content.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742958/how-to-compare-images-using-opencv-in-ios-iphone) might also be of your interest.

Comment: Vision API provides something in-house for image similarity  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/analyzing_image_similarity_with_feature_print